# php?cmd=SELECT 1+1 not found and SELECT 1-1 it works

Tags: php, mysql

please , I need help , it is so simple and can not find the reason , sending a query to php to return a json and a simple sum of a value to a field or other value do not realize , however subtractions if , What's up?
...//www.mipagina.com.mx/consultas.php?cmd=SELECT 1+1
SELECT 1 1\nYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
...//www.mipagina.com.mx/consultas.php?cmd=SELECT 1-1
[{"1-1":"0"}]
...//www.mipagina.com.mx/consultas.php?cmd=SELECT cantidad + 1 FROM timbres WHERE id = 2
SELECT cantidad 1 FROM timbres WHERE id = 2\nYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 FROM timbres WHERE id = 2' at line 1
...//www.mipagina.com.mx/consultas.php?cmd=SELECT cantidad - 1 FROM timbres WHERE id = 2
[{"cantidad - 1":"24"}]

Comment: Please format your question properly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode your sql query - the `+` sign is normally interpreted as a space in a url.  If you're manually encoding it, you'd need to replace the `+` sign with a `%2B`